# Why this Class-specific css affects completely other Classes?

Tags: html, css

So this is my css:

```
.errortable table {
  width: 716px; /* 140px * 5 column + 16px scrollbar width */
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.errortable tbody, thead tr { display: block; }

.errortable  tbody {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.errortable  tbody td, thead th {
  width: 140px;
}

.errortable  thead th:last-child {
  width: 156px; /* 140px + 16px scrollbar width */
}
```

It's affecting my target table as expected, however, it's affecting OTHER tables with completely different Classes.

It's affecting in particular the first td of ALL other tables regardless of their Class.

The first td are becoming very wide.

I've noticed that the other tables revert to their normal look when I remove the `.errortable tbody, thead tr { display: block; }`

My question is, why the errortable's css is affecting the specialtable class, what's wrong in my css that it's making it global and not class-specific?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Show HTML instead of an Angular template. Remove content from the table that isn't *needed* to demonstrate the problem. Show how the two tables related to each other in the DOM. Provide a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: "it's affecting ANOTHER table with a completely different Class." — in what way? What rules are being applied?

Comment: edited, and removed the angular part

Comment: Removing the angular part without replacing it with the HTML makes the question worse, not better.

Comment: no i removed it because it's not necessary, as I explained, it's making the first <td> of all other tables wide, with width 140px. that's the rule being applied on the other tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.errortable  tbody td,
thead th {
  width: 140px;
}
```

Your selector targets all `td` elements that are descendants of `tbody` elements that are descendants of elements with the `errortable` class **and** all `th` elements that are descendants of `thead` elements.

For the second half, you have no rule which says they must be descendants of elements with the `errortable` class.

Comment: So it should be  like this??  `.errortable  tbody  .errortabletd thead th {
  width: 140px; `
}

Comment: Don't remove the `td,`

Comment: sorry, i meant   `.errortable  tbody td,
.errortable  thead th {
  width: 140px;
}`     -- > is this how it should be?

Comment: Yes. It is easy enough to test too.

Comment: Thanks, i had to adjust my entire css like this: `.errortable table {
  width: 716px; /* 140px * 5 column + 16px scrollbar width */
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.errortable tbody { display: block; } 

.errortable  thead tr { display: block; }


.errortable  tbody {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.errortable tbody td, .errortable thead th { width: 140px; }

.errortable  thead th:last-child {
  width: 156px; /* 140px + 16px scrollbar width */
}`

Comment: now since i clarified my question and edited, would you be nice enough to remove your downvote?